# How to upload image to a database using webmatrix 3?

Tags: html, database, image, razor, webmatrix

I have two different cshtml pages. One is for creating a database and the second one is for showing the data. I don't know how to upload an image. Every time I upload a png file , it says "4 : Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'."
The datatype in the database is image

Here is the code:

```
@{
var ProductName="";
var ProductPrice="";
var ProductExpireDate="";
var ProductDescription="";
var ProductImage="";
  ProductName=Request["PName"];
  ProductPrice=Request["Price"];
  ProductExpireDate= Request["ExpireDate"];
  ProductDescription= Request["Description"];
  ProductImage = Request["Image"];
if(IsPost){
var SQLINSERT = "INSERT INTO ProductInfo (Name, Price, ExpireDate, Description, Image) VALUES (@0,@1,@2,@3,@4)";
var db = Database.Open("Product");
db.Execute(SQLINSERT, ProductName , ProductPrice, ProductExpireDate, ProductDescription, ProductImage);
//Response.Redirect("default.cshtml");
}
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title> MaxProducts </title>
    </head>

  <body>
        <div id="addProducts">
            <h2>  Product Information </h2>
                <form action="" method="post" name="ProductsForm" >
                  Name:<br>
                  <input type="text" name="PName"><br>
                  Price:<br>
                  <input type="text" name="Price"><br>
                  Expire Date:<br>
                  <input type="date" name="ExpireDate"><br>
                  Description:<br>
                  <textarea rows="10" cols="80" name="Description">                         </textarea><br>     
                  Image:<br>
                  <input type="file" name="Image"><br><br>
                  <input type="submit" value="Enter Product" name="EnterProduct"/><br>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure about the correct solution, but what I have done when I uploaded videos to a database, I set the file name to the database, and then when I need to pull it from the database I use a variable to pull up the video.

```
@foreach (var title in db.Query("Select * from vids" )){
    var toopen="Media/"+title.Title;
    <div id="item" class="playerdiv" onclick="window.open('@toopen','mywin','width:200px'); ">    
    <div style="margin: 10px">@RenderPage("thumbplayer.cshtml", new {
title=title.Title            
  })</div>
    </div>
```

Then when someone clicks on the image it opens it in a new window.  It's not elegant but it works for me.